# Why does getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/am") always return "Operation not permitted"?

Tags: java, android, linux, shell, permissions

My Android app targeting Android 5.0 contains some code as follows:

```
try
{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec("/system/bin/am switch-user 0");
    proc.waitFor();
    proc.destroy();
}
catch (Exception e)
{}
```

The simplest code above always returns 1 of `proc.exitValue`, which means ***Operation not permitted***.

However, I examined the permissions of `/system/bin/am switch-user 0` via `adb shell`, it showed as follows:

```
shell@hammerhead:/system/bin $ ll am
ll am
-rwxr-xr-x root shell 210 2015-03-23 15:10 am
```

Obviously, the permissions indicates any user can execute `am`.

What's more weird: I can successfully call `am` from `adb shell` (under unrooted mode).

I also tried to disable SELinux under rooted mode. The tests show that `setenforce 0` has no effects on Android 5.0, that is, SELinux is enforced on on Android 5.0. I can call `setenforce 0` without errors, but `sestatus` still shows "SELinux Enabled".

What's the root cause?

Comment: Are you aware of the proper way to call `Runtime.exec()` (or preferably use `ProcessBuilder`) ?

Comment: @Kayaman, ProcessBuilder returns the same error result. To make the thing simple, I did't provide the ProcessBuilder version.

Comment: Might be a SELinux issue, try "setenforce 0" but you need root rights

Comment: *What's the root cause?* obviously root is the root cause ... user id 0 == root

Answer (score 1):

I did some test on Android L emulator, if you execute `/system/bin/am`, it returns 0; if you execute `/system/bin/am switch-user 0`, it returns 1.

That means you *do* have the permission to execute `am`, but do not have permission to execute the command `am switch-user 0` in app.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a SELinux issue, try "setenforce 0" but you need root rights.
Also checking stderr might help http://pastebin.com/BeRYG1Hi

However an application can't have root rights. It can only be a System app, but is not the same thing as root.

Comment: I also tried to disable SELinux under rooted mode. The tests show that `setenforce 0` has no effects on Android 5.0, that is, SELinux is enforced on on Android 5.0. I can call `setenforce 0` without errors, but `sestatus` still shows "SELinux Enabled".

Comment: I think the problem is that you want your application to get root rights, that is not possible unless you find a hack(heard roumors about it). SELinux can be enabled but permissive.